# rsync : Copying all files into a destination directory with a different name

Tags: shell, zsh, rsync

Given: A source directory `/mnt1/src`, a destination directory `/mnt2/dest`.

Problem: For a daily backup, I want to rsync all files in the tree under /mnt1/src into /mnt2/dest, so that for example `/mnt1/src/foo/bar` ends up into `/mnt2/dest/foo/bar`. Files below `dest`, which have no corresponding entry under `src`, should be deleted from `dest`.

Environment: `zsh`

I tried

```
rsync --delete -ra /mnt1/src/*(D) /mnt2/dest
```

This nearly works, but has the problem that for instance if I have an extraneous file `dummy` inside `dest`, which was for instance produced by

```
touch /mnt2/dest/dummy
```

, this file would not be removed, because the globbing (`src/*(D)`) does not contain this file and rsync therefore ignores it.

Of course I could do a

```
rsync --delete -ra /mnt1/src /mnt2/dest
```

and this would remove such extra files, but a file `/mnt1/src/foo/bar` would then end up in `/mnt2/dest/src/foo/bar`, which I don't want either.

I could do a

```
mv /mnt2/dest /mnt2/src
rsync --delete -ra /mnt1/src /mnt2
mv /mnt2/src /mnt2/dest
```

and this would do the job, but it looks unnecessarily complicated to me. Is there a way to accomplish my goal, without renaming directories before and after?

Comment: I wonder who closed this question based on the assumption, that it would not be about programming. After all  I am trying to use the copying process as part of a zsh backup script, and zsh programming is for sure in the scope of Stackoverflow....

Comment: `rsync -ua --delete /mnt1/src/ /mnt2/dest` -- the trailing `'/'` after `src` tells `rsync` to copy *the contents of* `src` into `dest`. The `-u` only copies *new or updated* and `--delete` removes files not present under `src` in `dest`. (I suspect it was originally closed because it is a "How do I use `rsync`?" question that is more proper on [Unix & Linux](http://unix.stackexchange.com/))

Comment: Great! 2 minor points: (1) I think I should also use -r so that the directory trees below src are copied too.  (2) Why is `-u` necessary? AFIK, the whole purpose of `rsync` (at least with `-a` is to copy only things which have been modified since the last backup? Aside from this, may I suggest that you post this as an answer, as this will greatly simplify my backup script.

Comment: `-a` implies `-rlptgoD` -- you are covered. I didn't choose the options randomly...

Comment: Thanks a lot. Please post this as answer.....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per the comments, `rsync` is particular about whether there is a trailing `'/'` following the `src` operand. The presence or absence of the `'/'` controls whether the *"contents-of"* or the *"directory-itself"* is transferred, respectively. For example, in your case if you provide the trailing slash, e.g.

```
rsync --delete -ra /mnt1/src/ /mnt2/dest
```

Everything below `/mnt1/src` is transferred to `/mnt2/dest`.

If you omit the `'/'` following `src`, the `src` directory itself (and everything below it) is transferred, resulting in `/mnt2/dest/src/....` (not what you want)

Additionally, you can tweak your options a bit. In `-ra`, the `-r` is duplicative as `-a` implies `-rlptgoD`. To insure you only copy new and updated files, add the `-u` option.  The `--delete` option will delete files from `dest` not present in `src`.

Putting it altogether, you could accomplish what you are attempting with:

```
rsync -ua --delete /mnt1/src/ /mnt2/dest
```

If you would like to see what is being transferred, add `-v` for verbose output, or I like the `-i` summary output. Good luck with your scripting. Let me know if you have questions.